# Validar campo de un formulario HTML con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy creando una validación de mi formulario mas específicamente en el campo (Username) que según las validaciones  me retorne Falso o Verdadero, las validaciones son:
-el campo debe contener caracteres alfanuméricos, una longitud no mayor a 30 dígitos
-debe de requerírsele obligatoriamente ósea no debe quedar vacío

El problema es que no se como capturar el valor del  True o False cuando el usuario ingresa cualquier Username

Codigo js

```
const username = document.getElementById('Username');
const input_username= document.querySelectorAll('#Username');

const expresiones = {
usuario: /^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,30}$/, // Letras, numeros
}

const checkUsername = (e) =>{
switch(e.target.name){
    case "Username":
        if (expresiones.usuario.test(e.target.value)){
            //validación

        }else{
          //validación
        }
        
    break;
}
}

input_username.forEach((input_username) =>{
input_username.addEventListener('keyup',checkUsername);
input_username.addEventListener('blur',checkUsername);

});
```

Lo que hago es evaluar lo que ingrese el usuario con una expresión regular pero no se como capturar el resultado para que mi función devuelva ese resultado.

Se que funciona por que cuando ejecuto este código en la consola de mi navegador me devuelve el resultado

```
expresiones.usuario.test("carlos90")
```

Llevo varias horas tratando de dar con el chiste pero he podido, les agradezco su ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu pregunta no está muy clara. Si quieres obtener el valor que retorna la función `checkUsername` simplemente devuélvelo usando `return expresiones.usuario.test(e.target.value)`.

Te adjunto un ejemplo funcional. Cuando el usuario presiona una tecla, se disparará un evento que llamará a tu función e imprimirá por consola el valor que devuelve.

```js
const input_username= document.querySelector('#Username');

const expresiones = {
usuario: /^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,30}$/, // Letras, numeros
}

const checkUsername = (e) =>{
switch(e.target.name){
    case "Username":
      return expresiones.usuario.test(e.target.value)
    break;
}
}

input_username.addEventListener('keyup',(e) =>{
  console.log(checkUsername(e))
 });
```

```html
<input type="text" id='Username' name="Username">
```